# Passing all state to child in function based components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

Is it possible to pass all states implicitly to child component in function based components?

So example I have a parent component:

```
const Parent = ({ value, onChange, onKeyDown, setValue }) => {
    const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
    const [opened, setOpened] = useState(true);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

    return (
        <Children focused={focused}
                  opened={opened}
                  count={count}
                  setFocused={setFocused} 
                  setOpened={setOpened} 
                  setCount={setCount}/>
    );
};

export default Parent;
```

Can I reach all states from the children without explicitly setting them as parameters?
As far is I know in class based components I just have to do:

```
<Children  {...this.state} />
```

and I can reach all states in children.

Is there something similar in function based components?

Comment: You already got a few answers, but IMO when things start getting complicated with the state is time to start using Redux or any other state management tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single state object like Viet's answer (*and this is most similar to how you are using it in a class-component*), but you probably still want to maintain control over what is passed on to children components. If you don't want to explicitly pass each and every state as a prop you can collect them into an object first and pass the object.

```
const Parent = ({ value, onChange, onKeyDown, setValue }) => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(true);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  const childProps = {
    focused,
    setFocused,
    opened,
    setOpened,
    count,
    setCount,
  };

  return <Child {...childProps} />;
};
```

**Note:** I don't generally recommend passing the state updater functions directly though, as this offloads the responsibility to maintain the state invariant to all consuming children components. Instead you should declare state update handlers and pass these along instead. This is so the parent component maintains control over how its state is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one state like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  focused: false,
  opened: true,
  count: 1
});

<Children  {...state} setState={setState} />
```

And if you want change value of `focused`, you can do like that:

```
setState((preState) => ({ ...preState, focused: true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an object and send that object as a prop. I've used a function to return an object.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-leftpad-94qcc?file=/src/App.js) - add prop directly

```
export default function App() {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(true);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  const obj = { focused, opened, count, setFocused, setOpened, setCount };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child {...obj} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-liskov-mkc3t?file=/src/App.js) - with a function

```
export default function App() {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(true);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  function getObject() {
    return { focused, opened, count, setFocused, setOpened, setCount };
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child obj={getObject()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use useState and define all state and pass to child

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  focused: false,
  opened: true,
  count: 1
});

<Children  {...state} setState={setState} />
```

Comment: There is already an answer with this exact code, and it actually provides a brief explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer code-only answers generally aren't very helpful.